# Getting Roles for Group Membership Azure AD

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, adal

We got a ADAL premium license and we are able to assign more then one role to a user successfully. But we can across this problem where a user 'Rob' is in 2 different groups  i.e. (Group A and Group B) and we assigned Group A to 'Spanish Translator' and Group B to 'Chinese Translators'. So what we though was the user 'Rob' will be getting multiple roles assigned to him via group membership.But for some reason we are only getting one role 'Chinese Translators'.

Code Snippet that fetches user's role:

```
   ClaimsIdentity claimsId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
   var appRoles = new List<String>();
    foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindAll(claimsId.RoleClaimType))
    {          
    appRoles.Add(claim.Value);
    }
```

Just to make sure ,I also verified the user in portal and I did see the user getting assigned with two roles. But for some reason I'm only getting one role when the user signs-in.

Comment: Nikhil, this is suppose to work. Can you please give me your email address on http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/contact and we'll troubleshoot it together

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Dushyant. I just dropped my contact details on your blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nikhil, thanks for reporting this. We've identified the issue and are working on a fix - I shall update the thread as soon as it rolls out.